# last node value of a linked list is not being printed

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to traverse  a linked list and show the value of each node using node.I am using while loop here.But the problem is the last element of the linked list is not being printed.I had to print the last element seperately.

```
int print(){

    printf("\ncurrent list is \n");
    struct Node* showList;

    showList=head;
    while(showList->next !=NULL){

        printf("%d ",showList->data);
        showList=showList->next;
    }
    printf("%d",showList->data); // it prints the last element
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just change the condition to:

```
while(showList != NULL)
```

Then your `while` won't skip the last node. It is skipping the last node in the current state because obviously when you are at the last node then `showList->next == NULL` and the loop won't execute even though the node contains a value.

**Edit: Make sure you removed this line after the change or you'll have a problem:**

```
printf("%d",showList->data); // it prints the last element
```

---

Alternatively you could use a `for` loop:

```
for(showList = head; showList != NULL; showList = showList->next)
    printf("%d ",showList->data);
```

Comment: this crashes the program..it wont work .i tried that earlier

Comment: I don't see why it should crash the program... Maybe post the error? Or show the revised code after the change to make sure you didn't add some un-needed changes.. @AL-zami see my edit

Comment: Index off by one - error ? First item on array is 0 , Nth item is N-1. Or possibly change predecrement to postdecrement.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the last node in your list has `next` set to `NULL`. That is typical for a linked-list implementation.

If this is the case in your implementation, the condition for the `while` loop fails on the last node. In other words, `(showList->next !=NULL)` evaluates to false when `showList` is the last node.

To ensure that the last node gets printed, change the condition being tested. For example, you could simply test that `showList` is non-null.

Comment: yes last node->next is set to null..how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use while(showlist != NULL)
According to your condition, it won't enter into while loop for last element

Answer (score 1):

```
showList->next !=NULL
```

This condition is suitable for `for loop`

In the while loop you should use     `showList!=NULL` because in while loop   showList points to `NULL` after you exit the while loop